# Writing binary data to a file (from hexdump)

Tags: go

I try to do something very simple in Go but I do not manage to find any resources.

I receive an hexadump and I want to write it to a file but the content of both files (src and dst) do not match at all. Currently the only way I have find it's to manually add `\x` every 2 characters.

I tried to loop over my string and add `\x` the string looks identical but output is very different.

This code manually works:

```
binary.Write(f, binary.LittleEndian, []byte("\x00\x00\x00\x04\x0A\xFA\x64\xA7\x00\x03\x31\x30"))
```

But I did not manage to make it from string "000000040afa64a700033130"...

What i currently do (this is what I do in python3):

```
text := "000000040afa64a700033130"                                                                     
j := 0                                    
f, _ := os.OpenFile("gotest", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0600)                                    
for i := 0; i < len(text); i += 2 {                                    
    if (i + 2) <= len(text) {                                    
        j = i + 2                                    
    }                                                                                                       
    value, _ := strconv.ParseInt(hex, 16, 8)
    binary.Write(f, binary.LittleEndian,value)                                    
    s = append(s, value)                                                                     
}
```

Comment: What did you try? How are you decoding `"000000040afa64a700033130"` in order to get something different from your manually decoded version?

Comment: I think that https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/hex#Decode can be useful.

Comment: First post edited

Comment: the code at the end is written in go ? Can you show the python version. Otherwise, as mentioned, `hex.Decode` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hex data is in the from of a string and you want to write the raw bytes you'll have to convert it first, the easier way would be to use `hex.Decode`.

```golang
import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func foo() {
    stringData := []byte("48656c6c6f20476f7068657221")
    hexData := make([]byte, hex.DecodedLen(len(stringData)))
    
    _, err := hex.Decode(stringData, hexData)
    // handle err

    err := ioutil.WriteFile("filename", hexData, 0644)
    // handle err
}
```

Based on your use you could swap over to using `ioutil.WriteFile`. It writes the given byte slice to a file, creating the file if it doesn't exist or truncating it in the case it already exists.

Comment: Yeah it works. I dont remember what I did wrong because I did try this (from hex golang's doc) but probably had a typo somewhere!